# Создание функции вывода графиков для разных датафреймов

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график

Есть два датафрейма `df1` и `df2`.

`df1`:

```
   A B C   
0  1 2 3
1  4 5 6
2  7 8 9
```

`df2`:

```
   Z X V   
0  1 2 3
1  4 5 6
2  7 8 9
```

Нужно создать функцию, которая рисует рядом два графика, в которых отображается зависимость значений одного столбца от другого. Написал вот такую конструкцию:

```
def show_me_comparison(data1, data2, name):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
    data1.plot(x='A', y='B', kind='scatter', ax=axes[0])
    plt.title(name)
    data2.plot(x='Z', y='X', kind='scatter', ax=axes[1])
```

Ну и вызываю ее

```
show_me_comparison(df1, df2, 'Хороший график')
```

Собственно, вопрос в том, как правильно вписать в функцию обращение к нужным столбцам датафрейма, чтобы она стала универсальной для любого датафрейма. Что-то совсем не получается, уже много всего перепробовал. 
Хочу, чтобы было вот так:

```
def show_me_comparison(data1, data2, столбец1, столбец2, name):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
    data1.plot(x='столбец1', y='столбец2', kind='scatter', ax=axes[0])
    plt.title(name)
    data2.plot(x='Z', y='X', kind='scatter', ax=axes[1])   

show_me_comparison(df1, df2, A, B, 'Хороший график')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так переделайте функцию в универсальную, которая будет брать первую и вторую колонки датафрейма:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7], 'B':[2,5,8], 'C':[3,6,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Z':[2,5,8], 'X':[3,6,9], 'V':[4,7,10]})

def show_me_comparison(data1, data2, name):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
    data1.plot(data1.columns.values[0], data1.columns.values[1], kind='scatter', ax=axes[0])
    plt.title(name)
    data2.plot(data2.columns.values[0], data2.columns.values[1], kind='scatter', ax=axes[1])   

show_me_comparison(df1, df2, 'test')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE**

Со срезами:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7], 'B':[2,5,8], 'C':[3,6,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Z':[2,5,8], 'X':[3,6,9], 'V':[4,7,10]})

def show_me_comparison(data1, data2, name):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
    data1.plot(data1.columns.values[0], data1.columns.values[1], kind='scatter', ax=axes[0])
    plt.title(name)
    data2.plot(data2.columns.values[0], data2.columns.values[1], kind='scatter', ax=axes[1])   
    plt.tight_layout()

show_me_comparison(df1, df2, 'test')
show_me_comparison(df1, df2[['Z', 'V']], 'test')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, в данном случае такой вариант подходит. А вот как сделать обращение, если у меня в разных датафреймах нужны будут разные колонки?

Comment: Передавайте в функцию не датафреймы целиком (`df1`), а нужные срезы (`df1[['W', 'E']]`) к примеру.

Comment: Отличная идея, огромное спасибо! Пойду тестить